# Switch on rebuild Sitecore 9.0.2 issue

Tags: solr, azure-search

We are using `Azure search in Sitecore 9.0 update 2 version`,

We enabled `switch on rebuild option` to achieve 0 downtime during the rebuild.
Every time when indexes `(_sxa_web_index)` rebuilding we notice that this stragies are not working with
**Unpublish item** (when we check unpublish item or delete item) but working with **update or create item**.

No errors or exceptions in logs.

Comment: Here with unpublish item, do you mean checking Never-Publish to true only or you are actually publishing its folder after it? Can you check in your showconfig if you are using any customization to these event and try to debug that

Answer (score 2):

[Azure Search Switch On Rebuild feature](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/zero-downtime-index-rebuild-in-azure-search.html) is only relevant for the **full index rebuild**. When configured correctly, it tells Sitecore to perform index rebuild in a new index while keeping the current instance as the primary index. Once the new index is fully built, Sitecore will switch to the new index and make it the primary index, then the old one will be removed.

Behaviour you mentioned is not connected to the Switch On Rebuild functionality because **updating, creating, deleting and publishing items trigger incremental index updates rather than full index rebuild**.

Depending on how your indexes are configured, these incremental changes can be processed synchronously, asynchronously, based on an interval, etc. You can read more about different indexing strategies in Sitecore documentation [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/index-update-strategies.html).